# Java Array to ArrayList to Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array name "asset" with 4 number.
I then converted it to be stored in arraylist.
Then with the arraylist copy to another array.
Is this algorithm correct?
After adding 5 the array should be able to show 5 number now

```
List assetList = new ArrayList();
String[] asset = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; 

Collections.addAll(assetList, asset);

assetList.add("5");

String [] aListToArray = new String[assetList.size()];
aListToArray.toArray(aListToArray);
```

Comment: Define correct.  What's your actual goal, here?  Get a copy of an array?  Translate between arrays and ArrayList for an assignment?

Comment: you can probably do some type safety like List<String> but anyways I am not trying to get why are you coping to a list and copy them back.... had it been a Set I would have understood

Comment: it meets my requirements

Comment: not assignment but I just want to know if this way of doing is right

Comment: Why are you using array at all, if the number of elements are varying?

Comment: @RohitJain I use array at first because I want to fix the 4 number and then continue to add on

Comment: @user2822351. You can fix 4 elements in the list itself. It's simple, if your array is going to increase in size, then you don't need an array, but an ArrayList.

Comment: use assetList.toArray(aListToArray);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
aListToArray.toArray(aListToArray); // aListToArray to aListToArray itself? This would have given a compilation error
```

to this

```
assetList.toArray(aListToArray); // assetList to aListToArray is what you need.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just `Arrays.asList(asset);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make some simplifications:

```
List assetList = new ArrayList();
String[] asset = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; 

assetList.addAll(asset);

assetList.add("5");

String [] aListToArray = assetList.toArray(aListToArray);
```

Overall, the code is correct. However if you want to have a "dynamic array", or a collection of items that changes in size, then don't bother trying to keep something in array form. An arraylist will work fine.

Comment: how about having first 4 number to be fixed and the rest being dynamically added

Comment: If you mean having the first 4 values unchangeable, then why would you have them in a collection if you know what they are? What purpose would that be serving?